# Mild introduction to selective advantage of intelligence/nervous systems in animals?

Tags: evolution, species, central-nervous-system, intelligence

I have a general understanding of why intelligence, i.e. nervous systems in animals, is advantageous: processing information allows an animal to adapt to its environment dynamically and perform complex sequences of actions that an animal without a nervous system could not. Larger nervous systems potentially allow for more possibilities herein.

However, I am interested in a deeper understanding of the factors that cause a species to at first develop, and increase the size of, a nervous system, and different forms of cognition:

- what type of environment favors the development of a nervous system in a species?
- what type of environment favors life-long learning and adaptivity (neiroplasticity?) of a species (as opposed to a fixed neural structure after development in an organism)?
- what type of environment favors the development of goal-oriented planning (as opposed to simple impulse-response patterns)
- what type of environment favors development of "cognitive ability" in species?

**Do you know of a good book that addresses questions like this?**

Comment: Look at that https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003399

Comment: @J.A Thank you, that’s interesting. Though not precisely my question.